# Pandas: how to plot specific columns and cases?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like the following

```
    Zone    year    Intervention A  Intervention B
0   Zone 1  2005    0.896788        0.892161
1   Zone 1  2006    0.807323        0.809103
2   Zone 1  2007    0.758814        0.764219
3   Zone 2  2005    0.697728        0.699586
4   Zone 2  2006    0.649360        0.648350
5   Zone 2  2017    0.566785        0.571259
```

I would like to plot 4 different curves where on the x-axis I have the `year` and on the `y-axis` the value of the intervations.

The 4 curves are:

`Intervention A`  `Zone 1`

`Intervention A`  `Zone 2`

`Intervention B`  `Zone 1`

`Intervention B`  `Zone 2`

Answer (score 0):

First idea is use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and flatten `MultiIndex in columns`:

```
df1 = df.pivot(index='year', columns='Zone')
df1.columns = df1.columns.map('_'.join)

df1.plot()
```

Another one is filter separately each subDataFrame:

```
df11 = df.loc[df['Zone'].eq('Zone 1')]
df22 = df.loc[df['Zone'].eq('Zone 2')]

ax = df11.plot(x='year', y='Intervention A')
df22.plot(x='year', y='Intervention A', ax=ax)
df11.plot(x='year', y='Intervention B', ax=ax)
df22.plot(x='year', y='Intervention B', ax=ax)
```